# Microsoft Graph returns same items on drive search

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

When searching for the items on Group drive with the pagination, returned subset sometimes contains the same items.

Let's say I have 6 files on Group 1. Files are named File 1, File 2, File 3 etc.
With the query below, I get 3 random files e.g. File 2, File 5, File 6, and a nextLink odata because there are still 3 files that correspond to the search query.

```
/groups/<group-id>/drive/root/search(q='File')?$top=3
```

When I execute the next query (link from odata.nextLink which contains skipToken) returned subset most often contains the item from the previous result e.g. File 1, File 2, File 5.
So the final result of the search is:

```
File 1,
File 2,
File 2,
File 5,
File 5,
File 6
```

The last response doesn't have nextLink.

Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong?

Screenshots as proof (here, I have 8 files and selecting top 3):

```
Request Ids:

Page #1: b7200e0c-c2fd-434d-987b-2ebc44c5d5b7
Page #2: 56d947fa-3705-4cee-8fe5-d3b2ca7f9968
Page #3: 85b6d06a-4aa3-4c9e-aa6a-de18db2a4e27
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you share the request-id and date so we can look into this?

Comment: @Diana added request Ids.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your issue. I have created 6 files and tested this scenario a number of times, see below screenshot. It seems you are not sending the nextlink correctly.
[image]

Please try again using Graph explorer and post the screenshot here. If this issue persists for you then it is specific to your tenant and you will need to create a support request.

Comment: I've been able to reproduce it once again. Added screenshots in the initial question.